# Sugar CRM API add lead

Tags: php, api, sugarcrm

I have been trying to figure this out for days now.  I managed to get the following code to create the lead and add the name but for some reason it refuses to add the email address. I have checked and double checked `$_POST['email']` is being set and working correctly.

```
 $soapclient = new nusoap_client('http://www.domain.com/crm/soap.php?wsdl',true);
 $user_auth = array( 'user_auth' => array( 'user_name' => 'user', 'password' => md5('pass'), 'version' => '0.1' ), 'application_name' => 'soapleadcapture');
 $result_array = $soapclient->call('login',$user_auth);
 $session_id = $result_array['id'];
 $user_guid = $soapclient->call('get_user_id',$session_id);
 $err = $soapclient->getError();
 if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
 }

 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $nameParts = explode(' ',$name,2);
 $firstName = $nameParts[0];
 $lastName = $nameParts[1];
 $email = $_POST['email'];

// create lead
 $set_entry_params = array(
   'session' => $session_id,
   'module_name' => 'Leads',
   'name_value_list'=>array(
      array('name'=>'first_name','value'=>$firstName),
      array('name'=>'last_name','value'=>$lastName),
      array('name'=>'status', 'value'=>'New'),
      array('name'=>'phone_work', 'value'=>$phone),
      array('name'=>'primary_address_city', 'value'=>$city),
      array('name'=>'account_name','value'=>$acc),
      array('name'=>'email','value'=>$email),
      array('name'=>'lead_source','value'=>'Web Site'),
      array('name'=>'description','value'=>$desc),
      array('name'=>'team_id', 'value'=> '1'),
      array('name'=>'assigned_user_id', 'value'=>$user_guid)
   )
);

$result = $soapclient->call('set_entry',$set_entry_params);
```

Any help figuring out why it will not submit the email address would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this? Comment out your entire code, except for top part where you login and everything. Then put this in:

```
$response = $client->get_available_modules($session_id);

$response = $client->get_module_fields($session_id, 'Contacts');

var_dump($response);
```

...where Contacts in the second statement is the name of the module you want to get fields from. It should return all the fields for that module. Make sure the field is named email and not email1 or email_c or something like that. The first line will output every module so you can see the name of the module you need.

Answer (score 2):

$email is incorrect, should be $email1. This is SugarCRM primary email address field name.

Answer (score -1):

Just Change this line:

```
array('name'=>'email','value'=>$email),
```

To

```
array('name'=>'email1','value'=>$email),
```

And its done.